# CLion: CMake configuration for selected git branch?

Tags: clion

I have a C++ project that is big enough to take about an hour to be reconfigured when an active git branch is changed.
The naive workaround is to have a dedicated folder with a different name. It would require to open close the current project in CLion, open a new one and continue the developement on a separate branch without affecting the current one.

But is there a way to add, for example, a CMake configuration, that would create a build directory taking into an account the current branch name? In that case, when the branch is switched, another CMake config would be taken without breaking the existing project configuration.
[image]

Or is it not possible at all? I couldn't find a gir branch-related CLion macro in documentation.